# Permutation matrix and simple directed graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, directed-graphs, permutation-matrices

I have some code that works with [simple directed graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleDirectedGraph.html), but it is kinda slow.

So I converted it to use an adjacency matrix instead of keeping a list of pairs of nodes.

The code finds the equivalence classes of graphs (see [here](http://oeis.org/A000273) and [here](http://oeis.org/A052283)) by permuting the names of the nodes in the list of pairs. This works but is slow.

I was thinking one could use a [permutation matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationMatrix.html) to permute the nodes. So I tried to use p*m*p (where p is the permutation matrix and m is the adjacency matrix). This does not work very well as it seems to map edge 0->1 to 0->0.

Is there an easy way to permute the nodes of an adjacency matrix?

Comment: List of pairs of what? If you take the incidence matrix for the edges and vertices, multiplying by the permutation matrix on just one side will permute either the rows or the columns, but produce an equivalent graph. Is that what you're trying to do? Why are the nodes named? Is it just for the purpose of generating the graphs?

Comment: lists of pairs of nodes. i get that i should only multiply once. yes i am trying to find an equivalent graph. the nodes are named just by their index (0, 1 ... n-1). yes,  just want to generate the equivalence classes.

Comment: i am using the adjacency matrix, not the incidence matrix

Comment: Oh, I see that if you conjugate the adjacency matrix by a permutation matrix you get an isomorphic graph. Did you mean to write $pmp^{-1}$ or $pmp$? The first is correct. Why shouldn't it map $0 \rightarrow 1$ to $0 \rightarrow 0$? Does it do this when the graph has no self-loops? What is the graph and adjacency matrix you're getting this problem from?

Comment: i did pmp, not pmp-1. 0->1 should never turn into a self loop - this is supposed to be a simple directed graph. the graph has 3 nodes (0,1,2) and one arrow 0->1. also, pm and mp do not work, i will try pmp-1.

Comment: trying pmp-1 still seems to map a 0->1 to a 1->1.

Comment: But it cannot. An entry moves the same number of columns to the right as it does rows down, or columns to the left as rows up. This follows from $P(PA^T)^T=PAP^T, P^T=P^{-1}$, where $P^T=P^{-1}$ is the statement that in taking $P(PI)^T$, $I_{ii}$ goes to $I_{\sigma(i)i}$ to $I_{i\sigma(i)}$ to $I_{\sigma(i)\sigma(i)}$, where $I$ is the identity. So the entry is off-diagonal iff it's sent to an off-diagonal entry. So whether any entry has a nonzero diagonal, and the number of self-loops, must be preserved by the conjugation. There must be a bug in your code.

Comment: i have a bug :(

Comment: i fixed the bugs. the program works a lot faster now. thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it, no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let P be a permutation matrix such that $[x_1, ... x_n]P=[x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},...,x_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}],$ where $\sigma$ is a permutation - that is, each row vector is sent to the one with $\sigma(i)^\text{th}$ component the original $i^\text{th}$ component. Then, treating a matrix $A$ as a row vector, $A_{ij}=(AP)_{i\sigma(j)}=(AP)^T_{\sigma(j)i},$ so $(PAP^T)_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)}=((A^TP)^TP)_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)}=(A^TP)^T_{\sigma(i)j}=(A^TP)_{j\sigma(i)}=A^T_{ji}=A_{ij}$. Therefore $PAP^T$ re-indexes $A$ by a permutation $\sigma$ of the indices, as required.

Since re-indexing the identity matrix's indices leaves it unchanged, a corollary is that $PP^T=\operatorname{id},$ so that $PAP^T=PAP^{-1}$ is similar to $A$.